# How to define helper_method in application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following method in my application_controller

```
def primary_contact_pending_approval(opportunity)
    if current_user and current_user.account.already_signed?(opportunity)
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
end
```

how do I make this method as helper method, so that I can use it in the `views` also.

I tried

```
helper_method :primary_contact_pending_approval(opportunity)
```

and

```
helper_method "primary_contact_pending_approval(opportunity)"
```

but both gives syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want `helper_method :primary_contact_pending_approval`. This will make it available to your views, and then you can call it an argument.

Answer (score 0):

write only..

```
helper_method :primary_contact_pending_approval
```